# Why am I getting an InsufficientPermissionsToRoot error with SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, active-directory, ssrs-2012

Why am I getting an InsufficientPermissionsToRoot error with SSRS 2012? Below is the full error message in the logs.

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage+InsufficientPermissionsToRoot: L'utilisateur ne dispose pas des autorisations requises. Vérifiez que les autorisations suffisantes ont été accordées et qu'aucune restriction liée au contrôle de compte d'utilisateur (UAC) Windows ne pose problème.
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add your Active Directory account/group in SSRS "Folder Settings" and "Site Settings".[image: French UX example]